# Angular Simple Country Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, filter

Say you have

```
$scope.countries = [
{ id="7AFG",  name="Afghanistan"}, 
{ id="1B1",  name="Albania"},
{ id="4AL",  name="Algeria"},
{ id="1B2",  name="Andorra"}
]
```

and so on, and in your view you are displaying a product which has a countryID which would correspond with the ids shown above. For example

```
{{ product.address.countryID}}
```

which would be "1B1" or some such. What's the most efficient way to have the country name value from the list, to be displayed instead of the ID?

Do I need to write a custom filter and then apply it such as

```
{{product.address.countryID | myCountryFilter }}
```

or is there a more straightforward way that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your data in a factory and use a custom filter.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory('countriesFactory', function()
{
    var data = [
        { id:"7AFG",  name:"Afghanistan"}, 
        { id:"1B1",  name:"Albania"},
        { id:"4AL",  name:"Algeria"},
        { id:"1B2",  name:"Andorra"}
    ];

    return data;
})
.filter('countryFilterById', function($filter, countriesFactory)
{
    return function(id, keyStrToReturn)
    {
        var filtered = $filter('filter')(countriesFactory, {'id':id})

        if(filtered.length < 1){ return null; }
        if(keyStrToReturn){ return filtered[0][keyStrToReturn]; }

        return filtered[0];
    }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, countriesFactory)
{
    $scope.currentProductId = '1B1'; // for that demo
});
```

See this fiddle :
[filtering your countries](http://jsfiddle.net/tmpesLt6/2/)

Comment: This looks guna try it! Could you edit to show passing in countries as a scope varibale to the filter rather than from a factory?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to do this. First is using filter as you mention. Second is create lookup array from countries array and get country name from this array by id.

```
$scope.lookup = {};
angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(country){
    $scope.lookup[country.id] = country;
});
```

And then in your html file:

```
{{lookup[product.address.countryID].name}}
```

I create codepen for this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avQjYw